# Get image from Gallery, but won't crop

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

I have this code to retrieve an image from the gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 360);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 360);
 try
    {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), req_code);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        // Do nothing for now
    }
```

But even with the `intent.putExtra("crop", "true");`, after choosing the image, it won't display any crop activity or whatever... Why?

Comment: in your ``ImageView``, set scaleType to CenterCrop

Comment: that was actually very helpful! I'm going to do this until I found a proper way to crop the image.

Comment: well, if your image is very large, it would case an ``outOfMemory``  problem, you' d better follow google' s developer guide or use a library to crop large image.

Comment: yes, at least I have a solution temporarily!

Comment: ok, but you should be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not supposed to. Just because you put random extras on random `Intent` objects does not magically force third party apps to do things that they do not do.

Here is [the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT). Note that none of the extras that you list there are in the documentation. Hence, no third party app is necessarily going to expect those extras.

Android does not have a built-in image-cropping capability available to developers. There are plenty of image-cropping libraries available, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :
    (For getting image from gallary)

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            dialog.dismiss();
```

(After picked image from gallary call this )

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
                // Gallery request result
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                TEMP_PHOTO_FILE_NAME = new File(

                startCropImage();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            File f = new File(getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri));
            if (f.getName().startsWith(FILE_NAME)) {
                if (f.exists())
                    f.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void startCropImage() {


    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

  /**
     * Check if there is image cropper app installed.
     */
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();
            /**
     * If there is no image cropper app, display warning message
     */
    if (size == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        /**
         * Specify the image path, crop dimension and scale
         */
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        /**
         * There is posibility when more than one image cropper app exist,
         * so we have to check for it first. If there is only one app, open
         * then app.
         */

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                    res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        }
}
```

Comment: There is no `CROP` `Intent` in Android: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Talented programmers would use a library, rather than rely upon an undocumented solution that may or may not exist.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_PHOTO: //Select photo == 1
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                imageUri));
```